# Requiring unknown module "581".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler

Tags: react-native, navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am trying to do simple navigation using react-native-navigation. But When I just import navagations.js file in homepage.js I am getting the error

Requiring unknown module "581".If you are sure the module is there, try restarting Metro Bundler. You may also want to run `yarn`, or `npm install` (depending on your environment).

My navigations.js

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

export const goTo = () => Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      id: 'BottomTabsId',
      children: [
        {
          component: {
            name: 'HomePage',
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                fontSize: 12,
                text: 'Varas Home',
                icon: './icons/home.png' )
              }
            }
          },
        },
{
  component: {
    name: 'EmployeeDetails',
      options: {
      bottomTab: {
        text: 'Varas details',
        fontSize: 12,
        icon: './icons/home.png')
      }
    }
  },
},
      ],
    }
  }
});
```

I am not sure whats wrong here?. I did not use anything such "Metro Bundler".

Comment: Try to import the navigation.js but don't use it, and let me know the update.

Comment: I did, but still the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you only have used one import statement inside your navigation file, or require() statement.